# Highchart/Highstock is getting time wrong unix time

Tags: timestamp, highcharts, unix-timestamp

I am using highstock api with unixtime. My Unix times that I give to the API are

```
1449757140,
1449757200,
1449757260,
...
```

Which all should normally be around : `10.12.2015 - 15:XX:00`

But the graph shows something around `1970-01-17 18:42`, which is totally wrong. Can anybody tell what is happening here

Comment: I get the correct time when I do time*1000+3600000. Why is this so weird?

Comment: First, timestamps in JavaScript are millisecond based. Second, probably you have dates with timezone offset (I guess timezone +1h ;) ).

Comment: As said by @PawełFus multiply timestamp by 1000